# Custom authentication at the URL level, use ISAPI still with .NET or is there a new way?

Tags: iis, authentication, isapi

Is there a non-IIS way of authenticating users that is not with HTML?

I know I can create my own ISAPI filter for IIS, but I want to achieve the same thing, with .NET code and not integrate it with IIS.

Is there a way to do this now, with the latest .NET, or is ISAPI still the way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply your custom authentication for all contents, an ISAPI extension is required for IIS 5/6/7.

Greg's way only works for ASP.NET content on IIS 5/6. However, if you understand the Integrated Pipeline feature of IIS 7 well, you can configure an ASP.NET HTTP module like Greg's to apply to all contents.

MSDN and IIS.net can provide me more details if you do a search further.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [`IHttpModule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttpmodule.aspx) to do this type of thing, e.g.

```
public class AuthModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.AuthenticateRequest += OnAuthenticateRequest;
        context.AuthorizeRequest += OnAuthorizeRequest;
    }

    private static void OnAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // authenticate the user here...
        // (note that the sender argument is an HttpApplication instance)
    }

    private static void OnAuthorizeRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // ...then authorize their attempted action here, if needed
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the down-vote? This is the way to do it with .NET; particularly with IIS7. If you're down-voting, please leave a comment as to why, and what you believe the 'correct' method is.

Comment: OK, I wanted to roll it back, but seems that I could not make any change now.